# Allocating a new array when full?

Tags: c++

I have been tasked with taking an object's array (`arr` in my code) and, when it is full, allocating a new array which is twice the size, filling it with `arr`'s contents, and lastly deleting `arr`.

I have tried a few different ways to achieve this, but each has given me a bad memory allocation error. I get hung up when considering that `arr` is a part of an object and that the newly allocated array must also be a part of the object. The code snippet is within one of my object's functions.

```cpp
if(num_elements == max){
    int *temp_arr = new int[max];
    copy(arr,arr + max,temp_arr);
    delete [] arr;
    arr = new int[2*max];
    copy(temp_arr,temp_arr + max,arr);
    max *=2;
    delete [] temp_arr;
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)? Also, please, no screenshots of code. Type your code in here.

Comment: Is this a school or class or book assignment or exercise? If not then use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Ah, I should have clarified. I am not allowed to :/

Comment: And don't show images of code. Create a [mcve] and copy-paste the code *as text* into the question. Please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: 1) Allocate buffer that is twice the size.  2) Copy contents of current buffer to new buffer.  3) Delete current buffer.  4) Assign new buffer to make it the current buffer.  You should have been given these steps in your class.

Comment: It is not clear why you want/need `temp_arr`?

Comment: There is no point in copying the data twice. Remember that `arr` is just a pointer and that the `delete[]` operator do not "undeclare" the pointer, it just frees the memory, returning it to the memory pool; you can still use `arr` to point to another memory address (in this case, the new buffer content). Now, it's not clear what kind of error you are getting. I'd suggest reading the recommendations from the other reply.

Comment: I needed temp array because I thought I needed some way to hold all of the values while I deleted the original. I am not super familiar with the new and delete operations. At this point, I can load values into my resizing array and have the operation complete around 50% of the time. The other half of the time, the program crashes with no error.

Answer (score 1):

You are making two separate copies where only one copy is needed, just as your instructions tell you to do.

Try this instead:

```cpp
if (num_elements == max){
    int temp_max = max * 2;
    int *temp_arr = new int[temp_max];
    copy(arr, arr + num_elements, temp_arr);
    delete [] arr;
    arr = temp_arr;
    max = temp_max;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. I am using this in part to create a stack data structure. After implementing this, I am able to push a (moderately) large amount of elements into the array. About half of the time, this operation will end up as a success. The other half, the program crashes. I get no error messages. Do you know why this would happen in a general sense? All I am doing is adding values to the array and resizing it when the size limit is reached.

Comment: "*I get no error messages*" - you should be getting something. What does the crash actually look like? *"Do you know why this would happen in a general sense?*" - you need to debug your code to find out.

Answer (score -1):

In general, you should use `powers of 2` (e.g., `size=2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, ...`) to increase the capacity of an object's reserve.

[ External Link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/reserve/ ]